# Mergering two dataframes of the same dimension like interlocking fingers

Tags: r, excel

I have two dataframe of the same dimension.

```
Dataframe A:
a1  a2  a3
1   4   7
2   5   8
3   6   9

Dataframe B:
b1  b2  b3
10  13  16
11  14  17
12  15  18
```

And I want to merge the two data to form a dataframe as below:

```
a1  b1  a2  b2  a3  b3
1   10  4   13  7   16
2   11  5   14  8   17
3   12  6   15  9   18
```

May I know how can I do in R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
 do.call(cbind,lapply(seq_along(A), function(i) cbind(A[i], B[i])))
```

Or

```
 cbind(A,B)[order(c(seq_along(A), seq_along(B)))]
```

Or if the dimensions are the same

```
 cbind(A,B)[c(rbind(names(A), names(B)))]
```